# Eliminating warning in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am creating 3 jsp pages. There are 4 boxes with different id in each pages (i.e. box1, box2, box3, box 4 in page 1; box 5, box6, box7, box8 in page 2; box9, box10, box11, box12 in page 3). Below is the sample code in page 1:

```
<div class="dragableBox" id="box1">CAT</div>
<div class="dragableBox" id="box2">DOG</div>
<div class="dragableBox" id="box3">HORSE</div>
<div class="dragableBox" id="box4">TIGER</div>
```

In each page there is also a script. In the script I deliberately use all those ids above as parameters of a function. Below is the sample code in page 1:

```
dragDropObj.addSource('box1',true);
dragDropObj.addSource('box2',true);
dragDropObj.addSource('box3',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box4',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box5',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box6',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box7',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box8',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box9',true); 
dragDropObj.addSource('box10',true);    
dragDropObj.addSource('box11',true);    
dragDropObj.addSource('box12',true);
```

I must do this because as far as I know this is the only way for my program to work. The problem I encounter is that each time the program started, a warning appears:
    "The source element with id box5 does not exist"

Although the program still works fine with this warning, I still want to eliminate the warning.

My question here is:
How can I stop such warning from appearing?
Is there a kind of error catching method in HTML?

Comment: Can you tell where the warning appears on page?

Comment: I suspect you're using a dragdrop js from http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=drag-drop-custom.  That being the case..javascript does have a try/catch, however the better solution would be to not cause the error in the first place.

Comment: this should be tagged as a javascript question

Comment: "In the script I deliberately use all those ids above as parameters of a function" - Why?

Comment: @RaviJain thanks for your reply. I have solved my problem using a code from vdbuilder.

Comment: @sans481 thanks for your reply. I have solved my problem using a code from vdbuilder.

Comment: @Itiong_sh thanks for your reply. I have solved my problem using a code from vdbuilder.

Comment: @Gareth thanks for your reply. I have solved my problem using a code from vdbuilder.

Comment: @user1221330 If this solved your problem, consider accepting answer and/or upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (document.getElementById('box1')){
    dragDropObj.addSource('box1',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box2',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box3',true); 
    dragDropObj.addSource('box4',true);
}
if (document.getElementById('box5')){
    dragDropObj.addSource('box5',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box6',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box7',true); 
    dragDropObj.addSource('box8',true);
}
if (document.getElementById('box9')){
    dragDropObj.addSource('box9',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box10',true);
    dragDropObj.addSource('box11',true); 
    dragDropObj.addSource('box12',true);
}
```

EDIT:

A better solution:

```
groupFirstMember = 1;
if (document.getElementById('box5')){
    groupFirstMember = 5;
}
else if (document.getElementById('box9')){
    groupFirstMember = 9;
}

for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    dragDropObj.addSource("box"+str(groupFirstMember+i),true);
}
```

Comment: Oops, I was writing exact same code. Moreover, you can use `elseif` instead of three `if`.

Comment: @user1221330 No problem, that's what we're here for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the existence of element before adding them.

```
if (typeof document.getElementById('box5') !== 'undefined'){
    // continue
}
```

Comment: `if ( document.getElementById('box5') )`  can do the samething.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal, No it validates for both null and undefined.

Comment: @starx you're absolutely correct that not using typeof will validate for null and for undefined. However, in this limited situation, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @vdbuilder, Limited or not, solution has to be precise.

Comment: @starx True precision is a must. In this example if getElementById returns undefined then we obviously don't want to run the code in the if block. There is also no point in running it if getElementById returns null (although I can't think of why it would), so, in this program either conditional (with or without typeof) has the same result. .

Answer (score 0):

Try this: this will grab all 'dragableBox' on page and run 'dragDropObj.addSource(...,true);' on them if they have an id=box[x] without using JQuery:

```
boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('dragableBox');
for (i=0; i < boxes.length; ++i) {
  var id = boxes[i].id;
  if(id.substring(0,3)==='box')
    dragDropObj.addSource(id,true);  
}
```